# Create azure VM with non interactive login CLI

Tags: bash, azure, command-line-interface

I'm working on deployment of multiple VMs' on Azure platform. I'm having problem authenticating without web interactive Login. I'm going through authentication using service-principal. However as soon as i try to run a 'azure vm list' for instance, I get a message: The server failed to authenticate.

[image]

P.S. I could create VM using interactive login. However this way does not work for the automated deployment. I'm the owner, admin of the Trial azure subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing, you are using ASM instead of ARM. Unfortunately, for Azure CLI, service principal only work for ARM. See [this issue in GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli/issues/2040).

Luckily, there is an alternative for this. you can use `azure account download` or click https://manage.windowsazure.com/publishsettings to download a publish settings profile. And then, use `azure account import <the file name>` to login.

Notice that similar to service principal, publish settings profile only work for ASM. Microsoft Azure encourages you to use ARM instead of ASM, hence I suggest you to switch to ARM. Service Principal is Role-Based Access Control. That provides extra security. And, ASM is retiring, which means new service will only available in ARM.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of those 2 different modes. Do you know if I need Active Directory to be configured? At this stage I'm only testing azure. All i want to achieve is to be able to deploy several VMs through Linux box on Azure. I have written a script to do it. All it stops me is the interactive login.

Comment: If you are using ASM, no need to  use Azure AD or interactive login. You just need to download the publish settings profile and import it with command `azure account import <the file name>`

Comment: Thank you for help. I have sorted out the problem by hard coding login details to the top of my script. Azure still prompts with error asking for interactive login however it continues to execute the script-which works for me.

Comment: Azure CLI continues to work for you because ASM mode has stored your session. However, if your session expire, your script will not work. Hence, I suggest you to use `azure account import` instead of "azure login". The publish settings profile can last for 1 year.